# .htaccess mod_rewrite exclude root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a project with this code in the .htaccess:

```
# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

So now every request (except the explicit  files) is sent to the /app.php.

I would like to change that behavior:
If someone requests the domain without any further file or directory the index.php should be displayed. In all other cases the given behavior should be performed.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude the root folder you can use the following condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```